# PowerShell script to convert .reg files to PowerShell commands

Tags: beginner, programming-challenge, converting, powershell

This is a PowerShell script I wrote a while ago that converts Windows Registry files to PowerShell commands(`New-Item`, `Remove-Item`, `Set-ItemProperty` and `Remove-ItemProperty`), it supports conversion of all six registry value types (REG_SZ, REG_DWORD, REG_QWORD, REG_BINARY, REG_EXPAND_SZ and REG_MULTI_SZ), and you got it right, I figured out how to correctly convert binary types.

You can view my original script here:https://superuser.com/a/1615077/1250181

Today I improved it, and this is the final version of my script, I used `reg add` to add REG_BINARY values because Set-ItemProperty can't add them, I used commas instead of "\0" because that's the correct way to add them with `Set-ItemProperty`, and Registry PSProvider does only provide 2 PSDrives by default: HKCU: and HKLM:, so if the registry files modifies other hives I added the lines to create them.

Please review my code(Tested on PowerShell 7, lower versions may not work):

```
Function reg2ps1 {

    [CmdLetBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, Mandatory=$true)]
        [Alias("FullName")]
        [string]$path,
        $Encoding = "utf8"
    )

    Begin {
        $hive = @{
            "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" = "HKCR:"
            "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG" = "HKCC:"
            "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" = "HKCU:"
            "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" = "HKLM:"
            "HKEY_USERS" = "HKU:"
        }
        [system.boolean]$isfolder=$false
        $addedpath=@()
    }
    Process {
        switch (test-path $path -pathtype container)
        {
            $true {$files=(get-childitem -path $path -recurse -force -file -filter "*.reg").fullname;$isfolder=$true}
            $false {if($path.endswith(".reg")){$files=$path}}
        }
        foreach($File in $Files) {
            $Commands = @()
            if ($(Get-Content -Path $File -Raw) -match "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT") {$commands+="New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT | Out-Null"}
            elseif ($(Get-Content -Path $File -Raw) -match "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG") {$commands+="New-PSDrive -Name HKCC -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG | Out-Null"}
            elseif ($(Get-Content -Path $File -Raw) -match "HKEY_USERS") {$commands+="New-PSDrive -Name HKU -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_USERS | Out-Null"}
            [string]$text=$nul
            $FileContent = Get-Content $File | Where-Object {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)} | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
            $joinedlines = @()
            for ($i=0;$i -lt $FileContent.count;$i++){
                if ($FileContent[$i].EndsWith("\")) {
                    $text=$text+($FileContent[$i] -replace "\\").trim()
                } else {
                    $joinedlines+=$text+$FileContent[$i]
                    [string]$text=$nul
                }
            }

            foreach ($joinedline in $joinedlines) {
                if ($joinedline -match '\[' -and $joinedline -match '\]' -and $joinedline -match 'HKEY') {
                    $key=$joinedline -replace '\[|\]'
                    switch ($key.StartsWith("-HKEY"))
                    {
                        $true {
                            $key=$key.substring(1,$key.length-1)
                            $hivename = $key.split('\')[0]
                            $key = "`"" + ($key -replace $hivename,$hive.$hivename) + "`""
                            $Commands += 'Remove-Item -Path {0} -Force -Recurse' -f $key
                        }
                        $false {
                            $hivename = $key.split('\')[0]
                            $key = "`"" + ($key -replace $hivename,$hive.$hivename) + "`""
                            if ($addedpath -notcontains $key) {
                                $Commands += 'New-Item -Path {0} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null'-f $key
                                $addedpath+=$key
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                elseif ($joinedline -match "`"([^`"=]+)`"=") {
                    [System.Boolean]$delete=$false
                    [System.Boolean]$binary=$false
                    $name=($joinedline | select-string -pattern "`"([^`"=]+)`"").matches.value | select-object -first 1
                    switch ($joinedline)
                    {
                        {$joinedline -match "=-"} {$commands+=$Commands += 'Remove-ItemProperty -Path {0} -Name {1} -Force' -f $key, $Name;$delete=$true}
                        {$joinedline -match '"="'} {
                            $type="String"
                            $value=$joinedline -replace "`"([^`"=]+)`"="
                        }
                        {$joinedline -match "dword"} {
                            $type="Dword"
                            $value=$joinedline -replace "`"([^`"=]+)`"=dword:"
                            $value="0x"+$value
                        }
                        {$joinedline -match "qword"} {
                            $type="Qword"
                            $value=$joinedline -replace "`"([^`"=]+)`"=qword:"
                            $value="0x"+$value
                        }
                        {$joinedline -match "hex(\([2,7,b]\))?:"} {
                            $value=($joinedline -replace "`"[^`"=]+`"=hex(\([2,7,b]\))?:").split(",")
                            $hextype=($joinedline | select-string -pattern "hex(\([2,7,b]\))?").matches.value
                            switch ($hextype)
                            {
                                {$hextype -match 'hex(\([2,7])\)'} {
                                    $ValueEx='$value=for ($i=0;$i -lt $value.count;$i+=2) {if ($value[$i] -ne "00") {[string][char][int]("0x"+$value[$i])}'
                                    switch ($hextype)
                                    {
                                        'hex(2)' {$type="ExpandString"; invoke-expression $($ValueEx+'}')}
                                        'hex(7)' {$type="MultiString"; invoke-expression $($ValueEx+' else {","}}'); $value=0..$($value.count-3) | %{$value[$_]}}
                                    }
                                    $value=$value -join ""
                                    if ($type -eq "ExpandString") {$value='"'+$value+'"'}
                                }
                                'hex(b)' {
                                    $type="Qword"
                                    $value=for ($i=$value.count-1;$i -ge 0;$i--) {$value[$i]}
                                    $value='0x'+($value -join "").trimstart('0')
                                }
                                'hex' {
                                    $type="REG_BINARY"
                                    $value=$value -join ""
                                    $binary=$true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($delete -eq $false) {
                        switch ($binary)
                        {
                            $false {$line='Set-ItemProperty -Path {0} -Name {1} -Type {2} -Value {3}'}
                            $true {$line='Reg Add {0} /v {1} /t {2} /d {3} /f';$key=$key.replace(":\","\")}
                        }
                        $commands+=$line -f $key, $name, $type, $value
                    }
                }
                elseif ($joinedline -match "@=") {
                    $name='"(Default)"';$type='string';$value=$joinedline -replace '@='
                    $commands+='Set-ItemProperty -Path {0} -Name {1} -Type {2} -Value {3}' -f $key, $name, $type, $value
                }
            
            }
            $parent=split-path $file -parent
            $filename=[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
            $Commands | out-file -path "${parent}\${filename}_reg.ps1" -encoding $encoding
        }
        if ($isfolder -eq $true) {
            $allcommands=(get-childitem -path $path -recurse -force -file -filter "*_reg.ps1").fullname | where-object {$_ -notmatch "allcommands_reg"} | foreach-object {get-content $_}
            $allcommands | out-file -path "${path}\allcommands_reg.ps1" -encoding $encoding
        }
    }
}
$path = $args[0]
reg2ps1 $path
```

Usage example: .\reg2ps1.ps1 "path\to\reg.reg"

***Sample Input***:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS]
"DelayedAutoStart"=dword:00000000
"Description"="@%systemroot%\\system32\\dps.dll,-501"
"DisplayName"="Diagnostic Policy Service"
"ErrorControl"=dword:00000001
"FailureActions"=hex:80,51,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,14,00,00,\
  00,01,00,00,00,c0,d4,01,00,01,00,00,00,e0,93,04,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"ImagePath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,76,00,63,00,68,00,6f,00,73,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2d,00,\
  6b,00,20,00,4c,00,6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,53,00,65,00,72,00,76,00,69,00,63,\
  00,65,00,4e,00,6f,00,4e,00,65,00,74,00,77,00,6f,00,72,00,6b,00,20,00,2d,00,\
  70,00,00,00
"ObjectName"="NT AUTHORITY\\LocalService"
"RequiredPrivileges"=hex(7):53,00,65,00,43,00,68,00,61,00,6e,00,67,00,65,00,4e,\
  00,6f,00,74,00,69,00,66,00,79,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,\
  67,00,65,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,43,00,72,00,65,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,47,00,6c,\
  00,6f,00,62,00,61,00,6c,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,\
  65,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,41,00,73,00,73,00,69,00,67,00,6e,00,50,00,72,00,69,\
  00,6d,00,61,00,72,00,79,00,54,00,6f,00,6b,00,65,00,6e,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,\
  76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,49,00,6d,00,70,00,65,\
  00,72,00,73,00,6f,00,6e,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,00,\
  6c,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,00,00,00,00
"ServiceSidType"=dword:00000003
"Start"=dword:00000003
"Type"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS\Parameters]
"ServiceDll"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,\
  00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,\
  64,00,70,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ServiceDllUnloadOnStop"=dword:00000001
"ServiceMain"="ServiceMain"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS\Security]
"Security"=hex:01,00,14,80,8c,00,00,00,98,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,30,00,00,00,02,\
  00,1c,00,01,00,00,00,02,80,14,00,ff,01,0f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,\
  00,00,02,00,5c,00,04,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,ff,01,0f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,\
  05,12,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,ff,01,02,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,\
  20,02,00,00,00,00,14,00,8d,01,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,04,00,00,00,00,\
  00,14,00,8d,01,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,06,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,\
  00,05,12,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00
```

***Sample Output***:

```
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS" -Name "DelayedAutoStart" -Type Dword -Value 0x00000000
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS" -Name "Description" -Type String -Value "@%systemroot%\\system32\\dps.dll,-501"
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS" -Name "DisplayName" -Type String -Value "Diagnostic Policy Service"
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS" -Name "ErrorControl" -Type Dword -Value 0x00000001
Reg Add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS" /v "FailureActions" /t REG_BINARY /d 805101000000000000000000030000001400000001000000c0d4010001000000e09304000000000000000000 /f
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS" -Name "ImagePath" -Type ExpandString -Value "%SystemRoot%\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNoNetwork -p"
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS" -Name "ObjectName" -Type String -Value "NT AUTHORITY\\LocalService"
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS" -Name "RequiredPrivileges" -Type MultiString -Value SeChangeNotifyPrivilege,SeCreateGlobalPrivilege,SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege,SeImpersonatePrivilege
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS" -Name "ServiceSidType" -Type Dword -Value 0x00000003
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS" -Name "Start" -Type Dword -Value 0x00000003
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS" -Name "Type" -Type Dword -Value 0x00000020
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS\Parameters" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS\Parameters" -Name "ServiceDll" -Type ExpandString -Value "%SystemRoot%\system32\dps.dll"
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS\Parameters" -Name "ServiceDllUnloadOnStop" -Type Dword -Value 0x00000001
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS\Parameters" -Name "ServiceMain" -Type String -Value "ServiceMain"
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS\Security" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
Reg Add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DPS\Security" /v "Security" /t REG_BINARY /d 010014808c00000098000000140000003000000002001c000100000002801400ff010f0001010000000000010000000002005c000400000000001400ff010f0001010000000000051200000000001800ff01020001020000000000052000000020020000000014008d010200010100000000000504000000000014008d010200010100000000000506000000010100000000000512000000010100000000000512000000 /f
```

***Registry Editor View***:

[image]

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Windows much and have very little experience with the registry, so I have a hard time judging the functional parts. So most of my comments are about the code style.

- While PowerShell is not very sensitive when it comes to case, convention matters, and so does readability.

  - If a variable has multiple words in it, don't make it all lowercase with no separator. `$joinedLines` is conventional, but both `$joined_lines` and `${joined-lines}` are at least nicer than `$joinedlines`
  - Method names, property names and cmdlet flag names generally start with an uppercase letter. `Select-String -pattern "...".matches.value` works, but `Select-String -Pattern "...".Matches.Value` is more conventional.
  - But above all else, be consistent in terms of how you refer to each variable. `$Commands` and `$commands` are the same, sure, but if you pick one and and stick to it it gets easier to read.
- You can get rid of some duplication by re-using the same code for all three New-PSDrive command additions thanks to your `$hive` variable (if you remove the colons):

```
foreach ($root in $hive) {
    if ((Get-Content -Path $file -Raw) -match $root) {
        if ((Get-PSDrive).Name -notcontains $hive[$root]) {
            $commands += "New-PSDrive -Name $($hive[$root]) -PSProvider Registry -Root $root"
        }
    }
}
```

- Though if you do that, you'd have to replace `$hive.$hiveName` with something more like `"$($hive[$hiveName]):"` later on.
- You have a few `switch` statements where the only cases are `$true` and `$false`. It'd probably be clearer to just make those into `if` statements.
- You have a couple `if ($someVariable -eq $true)` and `if ($someVariable -eq $false)` -- you can just replace those with `if ($someVariable)` and `if ( ! $someVariable)`
- At one point, you go `$command+=$Command+="..."`, which *might* be intentional, but doesn't look like it. If it is, you should probably add a comment specifying that, and possibly spell the line out like `$command = $command + $command + "..."`.
- If you have multiple statements on a single line separated by `;`, consider splitting it into multiple lines instead (`for` loop headers not included)
- Code tends to look a lot more pleasant when statements and operators get some space to breathe. `for ($i=0;$i -lt $FileContent.count;$i++){` works exactly the same as `for ($i = 0; $i -lt $FileContent.count; $i++) {`, but the second is less of a hassle to read.
- As a Cmdlet, your `reg2psi` function should probably follow the `Verb-Noun` naming convention, with a name like `ConvertFrom-RegistryFile` perhaps?
- I'm not sure creating the `allcommands_reg.ps1` is your script's responsibility, and I'm also not sure it's well-behaved if you're working on a folder that contains a file called `allcommands.reg`. Might be best to just have your cmdlet create the individual `*_reg.ps1` files and making a separate script for combining them.
- The line joining removes *all* backslashes from lines that end with a backslash, which could be dangerous unless you know that a backslash will never appear in another position. Maybe that's the case (I don't know much about the Windows registry), but being explicit and replacing `\\$` instead is probably best.
- Also, when doing the line joining, you can just iterate over the lines directly rather than keeping track of an index:

```
foreach ($line in $fileContent) {
    if ($line.EndsWith("\")) {
        # stuff
    } else {
        # stuff
    }
}
```

- Once the lines are joined...

  - I *think* that first series of matches can be reduced to just one like `$joinedLine -match '^\[-?HKEY[^\]]*\]$'`. But again, I don't have much registry experience, I might be missing something.
  - If instead of treating the key as starting with `-` you treat the line as starting with `[-` you might be able to get rid of some duplication:

```
$key = $joinedLine -replace '^\[-?|\]$'
$hiveName = $key.Split('\')[0]
$key = '"' + ($key -replace $hiveName, "$($hive[$hiveName]):") + '"'
if ($joinedLine -StartsWith '[-') {
    # Add a Remove-Item command
} else {
    # Maybe add a New-Item command
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, after numerous fixes and improvements, this is the final version of the script. I have tested it rigorously and made sure it is working properly.

So here is the code:

```
Function reg2ps1 {

    [CmdLetBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Alias("FullName")]
        [string]$path,
        $Encoding = "utf8"
    )

    Begin {
        $hive = @{
            "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"   = "HKCR:"
            "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG" = "HKCC:"
            "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"   = "HKCU:"
            "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"  = "HKLM:"
            "HKEY_USERS"          = "HKU:"
        }
        [system.boolean]$isfolder = $false
        $addedpath = @()
    }
    Process {
        if (test-path $path -pathtype container) { $files = (get-childitem -path $path -recurse -force -file -filter "*.reg").fullname; $isfolder = $true }
        else { if ($path.endswith(".reg")) { $files = $path } }
        foreach ($File in $Files) {
            $Commands = @()
            foreach ($root in $hive.keys) {
                if ((Get-Content -Path $file -Raw) -match $root -and $hive[$root] -notin ('HKCU:', 'HKLM:')) {
                    $commands += "New-PSDrive -Name $($hive[$root].replace(':', '')) -PSProvider Registry -Root $root"
                }
            }
            [string]$text = $nul
            $FileContent = Get-Content $File | Where-Object { ![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) } | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
            $joinedlines = @()
            foreach ($line in $FileContent) {
                if ($line.EndsWith("\")) {
                    $text = $text + ($line -replace "\\$").trim()
                }
                else {
                    $joinedlines += $text + $line
                    [string]$text = $nul
                }
            }

            foreach ($joinedline in $joinedlines) {
                if ($joinedline -match "\[HKEY(.*)+\]") {
                    $key = $joinedline -replace '\[-?|\]'
                    $hivename = $key.split('\')[0]
                    $key = '"' + ($key -replace $hivename, $hive.$hivename) + '"'
                    if ($joinedline.StartsWith("[-HKEY")) {
                        $Commands += 'Remove-Item -Path {0} -Force -Recurse' -f $key
                    }
                    else {
                        if ($key -notin $addedpath) {
                            $Commands += 'New-Item -Path {0} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null' -f $key
                            $addedpath += $key
                        }
                    }
                }
                elseif ($joinedline -match "`"([^`"=]+)`"=") {
                    [System.Boolean]$delete = $false
                    $name = ($joinedline | select-string -pattern "`"([^`"=]+)`"").matches.value | select-object -first 1
                    switch ($joinedline) {
                        { $joinedline -match "=-" } { $Commands += 'Remove-ItemProperty -Path {0} -Name {1} -Force' -f $key, $Name; $delete = $true }
                        { $joinedline -match '"="' } {
                            $type = "String"
                            $value = $joinedline -replace "`"([^`"=]+)`"="
                        }
                        { $joinedline -match "dword" } {
                            $type = "Dword"
                            $value = $joinedline -replace "`"([^`"=]+)`"=dword:"
                            $value = "0x" + $value
                        }
                        { $joinedline -match "qword" } {
                            $type = "Qword"
                            $value = $joinedline -replace "`"([^`"=]+)`"=qword:"
                            $value = "0x" + $value
                        }
                        { $joinedline -match "hex(\([2,7,b]\))?:" } {
                            $value = ($joinedline -replace "`"[^`"=]+`"=hex(\([2,7,b]\))?:").split(",")
                            $hextype = ($joinedline | select-string -pattern "hex(\([2,7,b]\))?").matches.value
                            switch ($hextype) {
                                { $hextype -match 'hex(\([2,7])\)' } {
                                    $ValueEx = '$value = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $value.count; $i += 2) {if ($value[$i] -ne "00") {[string][char][int]("0x" + $value[$i])}'
                                    switch ($hextype) {
                                        'hex(2)' { $type = "ExpandString"; invoke-expression $($ValueEx + '}') }
                                        'hex(7)' { $type = "MultiString"; invoke-expression $($ValueEx + ' else {","}}'); $value = 0..$($value.count - 3) | % { $value[$_] } }
                                    }
                                    $value = $value -join ""
                                    if ($type -eq "ExpandString") { $value = '"' + $value + '"' }
                                    else {$value = foreach ($seg in $value.split(',')) {'"' + $seg + '"'}; $value = $value -join ','}
                                }
                                'hex(b)' {
                                    $type = "Qword"
                                    $value = for ($i = $value.count - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--) { $value[$i] }
                                    $value = '0x' + ($value -join "").trimstart('0')
                                }
                                'hex' {
                                    $type = "Binary"
                                    $value = $value | %{'0x' + $_}
                                    $value = '([byte[]]$(' + $($value -join ",") + '))'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!$delete) {
                        $Commands += 'Set-ItemProperty -Path {0} -Name {1} -Type {2} -Value {3} -Force' -f $key, $name, $type, $value
                    }
                }
                elseif ($joinedline -match "@=") {
                    $name = '"(Default)"'; $type = 'string'; $value = $joinedline -replace '@='
                    $commands += 'Set-ItemProperty -Path {0} -Name {1} -Type {2} -Value {3}' -f $key, $name, $type, $value
                }
            
            }
            $Commands | out-file -path $($file.replace('.reg', '_reg.ps1')) -encoding $encoding
        }
        if ($isfolder) {
            $allcommands = (get-childitem -path $path -recurse -force -file -filter "*_reg.ps1").fullname | where-object { $_ -notmatch "allcommands_reg" } | foreach-object { get-content $_ }
            $allcommands | out-file -path "${path}\allcommands_reg.ps1" -encoding $encoding
        }
    }
}
$path = $args[0]
reg2ps1 $path
```

This is truly the final version.

The fixes include:

1. Using a loop to add `HKCR`, `HKCC` and `HKU` PSDrives if necessary.
2. Removed unnecessary `$binary` boolean.
3. Added quotes to each substrings in a multistring value to ensure the command will run correctly if the substrings contain spaces.
4. Fixed a bug that removes colons from a `$key` variable and causes `set-itemproperty` commands modify keys without a colon, this would occur if the key contains a `reg_binary` value and the value the `set-itemproperty` line modifies comes after the `reg_binary` value in the same key.
5. Implemented the correct way to modify `REG_BINARY` values using `Set-ItemProperty`, so that `reg add` commands are not needed and the script thus becomes 100% PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

1. In reg value text that contains escape characters like "cmd.exe /s /k pushd "%V"" your conversion doesn't replace " with `" or similar.
2. You need New-ItemProperty rather than Set-ItemProperty when using -Type property.
3. Out-File path parameter is -FilePath not -Path
   Probably worth fixing